# Данные с поля в сторе приходят не сразу, а спустя некоторое время, с чем это может быть связано?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-middleware

У меня есть компонент TopLane, ему с reducer пробрасывает поле в котором должны быть данные, но они приходят не сразу, лишь только после 2-го раза, не могу понять почему так((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код самого TopLane

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import a_icon_arrow_back from '../../../../../../assets/img/product/a_icon_arrow_back.svg';
import arrow_default from '../../../../../../assets/img/product/_a.icon.arrow.default blue.svg'
import export_blue from '../../../../../../assets/img/product/_a.icon.export_blue.svg';

import '../../../../../../assets/scss/pages/product/_top_lane_audit.scss';
import {ProgressBarColored} from 'serpstat-components/Common/ProgressBars/ProgressBarColored';
import ProgressBarSimple from 'serpstat-components/Common/ProgressBars/ProgressBarSimple';
import Dropdown from 'serpstat-components/Common/Dropdowns/Dropdown';
// import index from 'serpstat-components/Common/dropdown-select/index';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchRequest} from 'serpstat-actions/audit2.0/fetchRequest';

import DataRange from 'serpstat-components/Projects/Audit_2.0/common/DataRange/DataRange';
import DataPicker from 'serpstat-components/Common/Datepicker/DateRange';
import {isActiveCompare, isActiveExport, isActiveDropBox} from 'serpstat-actions/audit2.0/isActive';
import {
    getErrorInfoOneRequest,
    getErrorInfoOTwoRequest,
    getErrorInfoThreeRequest,
    getErrorInfoFourRequest,
    getErrorInfoFiveRequest,
} from 'serpstat-actions/audit2.0/getErrorInfo';
import {getLimitRequest} from '../../../../../../redux/actions/audit2.0/getLimit';

import MainTitle from 'serpstat-components/Projects/Audit_2.0/common/components/MainTitle/MainTitle';
class TopLane extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchRequest();
        // console.log(this.props.errorTypeOne);
        // this.props.getErrorInfoOneRequest();
        // this.props.getErrorInfoOTwoRequest();
        this.props.getErrorInfoThreeRequest();
        this.props.getLimitRequest();
        // this.props.getErrorInfoFourRequest();
        // this.props.getErrorInfoFiveRequest();
    }

    // componentWillMount(){
    //     this.props.getErrorInfoOneRequest();

    // }


    render() {
        // console.log(this.props);
        const {addLimit} = this.props;
        const {result} = addLimit;
        console.log(addLimit);
        return (
            <div>
                {/* <MainTitle data={this.props.toggleClass}/> */}
                {/* <DataRange/> */}

                <div className='bread_crumbs' onClick={this.props.handleClick}>Site audit summary / All errors and recommendations</div>


                <div className='top_wrapper'>
                    <h3 className='main_text'>
                        <img src={a_icon_arrow_back} className="aiconarrowback"/>
                        <span className='margin_text error_size'>Errors:</span>
                        <span className='text_size'>dropbox</span>
                        <span className='margin_text text_size'>|</span>
                        <span className='text_size' onClick={this.props.isActiveDropBox}>dropbox2</span>               
                    </h3>

                <div className='limit_export_container'>
                    <div className='container_limit'>
                    {/* {result.used < 100 ? <span>лимиты исчерпаны</span>: 
                    `${<p>Limits: {result.left}/{result.total}</p>} ${<div className='widthProgress'><ProgressBarColored curr={result.left} max={result.total} color={"green"} /></div>}`
                    } */}


                    </div>

                {/* <DataPicker/> */}

                        <span className='margin_export' onClick={this.props.isActiveCompare}>
                            Compare with: 17 Sep
                            <img src={arrow_default} className='arrow_compare'/>
                        </span>
                        {/* <div className='position'><DataRange/></div> */}
                        <span className='margin_export' onClick={this.props.isActiveExport}>
                        <img src={export_blue} className='export_image'/>                             
                             Export
                        </span>


                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TopLane.propTypes = {

};

function mapStateToProps (store){
    return {
        toggleClass: store.allErrorAudit.toggleClass,
        errorTypeOne: store.allErrorAudit.dataErrorList.errorTypeOne,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        getErrorList: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorList());
        },

        getErrorInfoOneRequest: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorInfoOneRequest())
        },
        getErrorInfoOTwoRequest: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorInfoOTwoRequest())
        },
        getErrorInfoThreeRequest: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorInfoThreeRequest())
        },
        getErrorInfoFourRequest: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorInfoFourRequest())
        },
        getErrorInfoFiveRequest: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorInfoFiveRequest())
        },



        getErrorInfoOne: function (){
            dispatch(getErrorInfoOne())
        },
        fetchRequest: function (){
            dispatch(fetchRequest())
        },
        isActiveCompare: function (){
            dispatch(isActiveCompare())
        },
        isActiveExport:function (){
            dispatch(isActiveExport())
        },
        isActiveDropBox: function (){
            dispatch(isActiveDropBox())
        },
        // getDataSetError: function (){
        //     dispatch(getDataSetError())
        // }
        getLimitRequest: function (){
            dispatch(getLimitRequest())
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TopLane);
```

worker in saga

```
    import { getMockData } from "serpstat-api";
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {getLimitSucceed} from '../../../../actions/audit2.0/getLimit';


import p from '../../procedures';

  export default function*() {
    try {
      const data = yield call(getMockData, p["limits.getLimit"]);





        yield put(getLimitSucceed(data));

    } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);

    }
  }
```

Reducer`

```
import * as t from '../../../constants/audit2.0';
export default function addLimitReducer (state = [], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case t.GET_LIMIT_SUCCEED:
        return action.data;
        default: return state;
    }
}`
```

Actions

```
import * as t from "../../constants/audit2.0";

export const getLimitRequest = () => ({
    type: t.GET_LIMIT_REQUEST,
  });


  export const getLimitSucceed = (data) => ({
    type: t.GET_LIMIT_SUCCEED,
    data,
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как я понял, ты делаешь 3 запроса в componentDidMount. Тебе нужно создать метку, которая переходит в true, когда получаешь ответ по всем трем запросам и рендерить компонент только тогда. До получения ответа можно отрендерить какой-нибуль лоадер

Comment: А если не использовать метку - типа дополнительного поля(true) в store и не делать проверку на то пришли ли данные, показывает лоадер то по другому ничего и не выйдет ?

Comment: Каждый раз как приходит ответ с завпроса (у тебя из 3 штуки) - обновляется стор. Соответственно показывать данные ты должен те, что придут в ответе. Без метки можно так: проинициализировать поле как null, в рендере поставить условие - если поле null - рендерить лоадер, иначе (значит данные пришли) как обычно. Но если в ответе придет null, лоадер будет бесконечным. Ты должен быть уверен, что null не придет

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое)) Ещё вариант проверять длинну массива на 0 - рисуется лоадер, если же не 0 то уже то что мне нужно.

Comment: В общем спасибо за помощь!))